# Unable to Record Audio with Bluetooth LE device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I was tinkering around creating a Voice Recorder in android.
I was able to record audio and play it back. I am even able to record audio when a standard bluetooth headset(Bluetooth 2.X) is connected.

However, when i connect a BLE headset(Bluetooth 4.X) to my phone i am not able to record any audio, and i am not able to figure out why?

Any idea what am i missing?

Here's my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Comment: What is your detailed recording scenario for Bluetooth headsets? BLE here is mostly about hardware. Generally it uses the same profiles (A2DP and HFP/HSP) to stream audio.

Comment: Turns out the hardware which i was using had problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth 4.X **adds** LE transport alongside "Classic" Bluetooth transport (called BR/EDR). A headset is surely not LE-only, because today's audio profiles use BR/EDR as transport, so when it comes to a Bluetooth headset there is little difference between 2.1 and 4.X.

So if the app worked with a 2.1 headset, it should work with any headset. Your problem is somewhere else -- either the new 4.X headset is broken or is not properly configured.

Comment: Yup. Turns out it was a problem with the hardware which i was using. Thanks!